# 'positions.isNotEmpty': PageController.page cannot be accessed before a PageView is built with it. Carousel Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to call a List ((locating outside the build(BuildContext context) Widget)) in the BottomNavigationBar. The list contains a stateful Widget (containing a carousel slide). So when ever i re-run my project and scroll the page i get this error keep coming continuously.It says

```
E/flutter ( 6022): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 180 pos 7: 'positions.isNotEmpty': PageController.page cannot be accessed before a PageView is built with it.
E/flutter ( 6022): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:42:39)
E/flutter ( 6022): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:38:5)
E/flutter ( 6022): #2      PageController.page (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:180:7)
E/flutter ( 6022): #3      CarouselState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:carousel_pro/src/carousel_pro.dart:110:24)
E/flutter ( 6022): #4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter ( 6022): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter ( 6022): #6      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:987:7)
E/flutter ( 6022): #7      _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1024:26)
E/flutter ( 6022): #8      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1196:13)
E/flutter ( 6022): #9      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter ( 6022): #10     _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1008:26)
E/flutter ( 6022): #11     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter ( 6022): #12     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter ( 6022): #13     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

the code is below

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can check whether the `PageController` has any pages before performing any operations on it.
Do it this way:

`pageController.hasClients ? pageController.page(2) : pagecontroller.initialPage;`

I would've been of much help if you had copied and pasted your code instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

the `PageView` to which the `PageController` belongs to will be built in build function so you cannot access the page before its being built in initState or anything before that

you gotta add a listener to `PageController` to listen for scroll changes

Comment: how do I add listener to Pagecontroller?

Comment: I have the same problem.